# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main PID: 4435

Tags: android, camera

Using Emulator I'm running into theese errors when I try to start camera:
I've tried to rebuild, restart and different Emulator but not working
How to fix it?
Thanks in Advance

```
09-03 18:43:58.349 4435-4435/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker, PID: 4435
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find requested camera.
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.zzchq(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.start(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview.startIfReady(CameraSourcePreview.java:86)
        at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview.access$100(CameraSourcePreview.java:31)
        at com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview$SurfaceCallback.surfaceCreated(CameraSourcePreview.java:109)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:618)
        at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:161)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2205)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot run a application on emulator which required a Physical Resource to run like camera, sensors. To test such kind of applications you need a real device with working resources.

Emulator is just a virtual device with real image of android OS

Comment: OK, I know but 30 minute ago all worked fine. Why now not working and show me theese errors?

Comment: may be 30 minutes ago you app did not request the camera resource yet and all working smoothly. Now you app suddenly request for camera resource and it crashed look at error "Could not find requested camera"
In emulator you just can use software features of mobile phone not physical one

Comment: I have understood. Thanks a lot